# Advise on how to start with SharePoint Online/Office 365 Subscription and Development

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have done full trust farm level deployments (on-premise) till now and have no idea of SharePoint online/Office 365 development and deployment for SharePoint Apps, SharePoint Framework and PowerApps etc.

I would like to purchase Office 365 subscription for developing and deploying my own apps for my learning. Please advise on which plan/subscription I need to take.

I have Visual Studio with Office Developer Tools installed on my notebook, and when deploying, I want to point to SharePoint site on Office 365. Another question, can I create new users after I purchase my subscription so that I verify my apps with different logins with different permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the [Office 365 Developer Program](https://dev.office.com/devprogram) for free. One of the benefits of this program is an Office 365 developer tenant that is good for one year. It's important to note that this developer tenant **does not** come with Azure credits.

[image: Developer program benefits]

Certain MSDN subscriptions include an Office 365 Developer tenant as a benefit. Those subscriptions will also include $150 in Azure credits. You can check your MSDN subscription portal for more information and to see if you qualify.

[image: MSDN subscription]

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I will subscribe for the program.